# Best practice to manage Apache Cayenne "...project.xml" file

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

Apache Cayenne keeps a "...project.xml" file within the resources directory. This file contains the password to the database. This is a problem because the [deployment server] password should not visible to developers. Further, it would need to be a different user/password and connection to a different database during development.

What is the best practice to manage this "...project.xml" when using Cayenne? Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Instead of putting the database connection info (incl. password) into the XML file, **is it possible to inject the info programatically into the DataSource object**? If so, I can load the info from a config file when the app starts and then inject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. There is a "cayenne.jdbc.password" property that can be used to define DataSource password in runtime. It can be applied in two alternative ways:

1. As a system property on command line:

   `java -Dcayenne.jdbc.password=xxxxx`
2. Via injection:

   `ServerModule.contributeProperties(binder)
           .put(Constants.JDBC_PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "xxxxx");`

This and other config properties are [documented here](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.0/cayenne-guide/configuration-properties.html).